# How can I use Java WebService to push data to client

Tags: web-services, network-programming, client-server, java-ws

I have some CMS. and have a requirement that these CMS can send article together whenever needed.
I think I can use WebService to solve my problem by do following:

1. CMS-01 invoke WS by sending data(article and received CMS(s)) when it want to send an article
2. Webservice receive data and push to other CMS(s) which CMS-01 have selected.

But I don't know how to use WS to push data to client(s).
I use Java and Axis to develop my WebService and all my CMS written by Java

Answer (score 1):

The push version of ajax is sometimes called "comet".

I found these articles on the subject.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/

http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/cometslideshow.html